# checking whether an object is present in a List of Objects on the basis of some member variable

Tags: java

suppose I have defined a List as

```
private BlockingQueue<MyDelayed> DelayedIds = new DelayQueue<>();
```

class `MyDelayed` is like:
private class MyDelayed implements Delayed {

```
    private String myId;
    private Long creationTime;

    MyDelayed (String myId) {
       this.myId= myId;
       this.creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    String getMyId() {
        return this.myId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
      //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        //TODO
    }  
}
```

Now suppose that I want to add an Object of class `MyDelayed` in `DelayedIds` list.
I can do it by using `add` function.

But If I want to add obbject in list only if list does not contain an object of class `MyDelayed` which has the same `myId` attribute which I am trying to insert.

Obviously `DelayedIds .contains(new MyDelayed(myId))` will not work.

Is there any easy way to check this thing ?
Am I missing something ?

Comment: You could start with implementing `equals` (and `hashCode`) in `MyDelayed`.

Comment: yes, I was also thinking about overriding equals function but how will I call that function ?

Comment: [`BlockingQueue.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) will call it for you so you don't have to do anything but to implement `equals` so that two objects having the same ids are considered equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this and compare every element in the list to see if it contains your id. If at any point you find a matching one you return true, if the loop finished having found none it returns false.

```
public boolean contains(String id){
    for (MyDelayed md : DelayedIds){ 
        if(md.getMyId().equals(id)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now to check before adding you would do something like:

```
if(!contains(myNewObject.getMyId())){
    DelayedIds.add(myNewObject)
}
```

Also, I'd suggest that you rename DelayedIds to delayedIds in order to follow [coding standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (see Variables).